# jQuery .html() not displaying all content

Tags: jquery

I am connecting to a database to retrieve data via ajax/JSON. The data writes into a Javascript keyed array. The result is displayed in a  container with a type down text field above it.

I loop through the array find the matching items and add them to the variable "theHTML" as a  row with three cell 's in the row - once the loop is complete I display "theHTML" in the container .

Everything works fine when the type downfield is empty the entire array is displayed correctly rows with cells.

As soon as one character is typed in the type down text field the display only shows rows and no cell content in the row.

I'm really not sure what I'm missing on this.

```
function dputracks_list_typedown(){

//clear display container by letting user know we are limiting it
$('#dputracks_list_dg').text("type down called..."); 

//empty var to add results of loop to
var theHTML = "";

//get text from search field and make lower case
var ttxt = $.trim($('#dputracks_list_typedown_txt').text()).toLowerCase(); 

//start a loop through the tracks_arr
for(i=0;i<tracks_arr.length;i++){

//in tracks_arr get same number of characters as search field 
//and make lower case so we can check for an exact match  
var atxt = $.trim(tracks_arr[i]'traname'].substring(0,ttxt.length)).toLowerCase();

// if we have a match then add the match in tracks_arr to the html we want
//to display in the container one <div row> with 3 <div cells> inside
if(ttxt == atxt){
theHTML += '<div class="dg_row">';
theHTML += '<div class="dg_cell"><b>'+tracks_arr[i]['traname']+'</b></div>';
theHTML += '<div class="dg_cell">'+tracks_arr[i]['trastate']+'</div>';
theHTML += '<div class="dg_cell">'+tracks_arr[i]['trvisits']+'</div>';
theHTML += '</div>';

//end of loop and if
};};

//if there are matches "theHTML" length will be greater than 10
//display result or tell user there was not a match
if(theHTML.length > 10){
$('#dputracks_list_dg').html(theHTML);
}else{
$('#dputracks_list_dg').text("No tracks returned");
};

//end of function
};

//keyup on search field to trigger search
$('#dputracks_list_typedown_txt').keyup(function(){dputracks_list_typedown();});
```

if I type "00 -" in the type down text field "theHTML" becomes:

```
<div class="dg_row">
<div class="dg_cell"><b>00 - Use New</b></div>
<div class="dg_cell">Aa</div>
<div class="dg_cell">&amp;</div>
</div>
<div class="dg_row">
<div class="dg_cell"><b>00 - Use New</b></div>
<div class="dg_cell">Aa</div>
<div class="dg_cell">&amp;</div>
</div>
<div class="dg_row">
<div class="dg_cell"><b>00 - Use New</b></div>
<div class="dg_cell">Aa</div>
<div class="dg_cell">&amp;</div>
</div>
<div class="dg_row">
<div class="dg_cell"><b>00 - Use New</b></div>
<div class="dg_cell">Aa</div>
<div class="dg_cell">&amp;</div>
</div>
<div class="dg_row">
<div class="dg_cell"><b>00 - Use New</b></div>
<div class="dg_cell">Aa</div>
<div class="dg_cell">&amp;</div>
</div>
<div class="dg_row">
<div class="dg_cell"><b>00 - Use New</b></div>
<div class="dg_cell">Aa</div>
<div class="dg_cell">&amp;</div>
</div>
```

But what gets displayed is:

```
<div class="dg_row"></div>
<div class="dg_row"></div>
<div class="dg_row"></div>
<div class="dg_row"></div>
<div class="dg_row"></div>
<div class="dg_row"></div>
```

Backspace the search field to no characters and the entire list displays correctly. The rows with cells and text are all there.

[image: Console screen shot]

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Well done on you first question! Good to show samples and code! 
To increase your chances of getting an answer on this, try to better organise your first paragraph to make it more readable: check your spelling, your punctuation and divide it in paragraphs - one for the situation and one for the problem for instance. This just makes it easier and more attractive to read....

Comment: Can you provide a sample of what `tracks_arr` looks like? Maybe try creating a JSFiddle which shows the problem? Are there any errors or msgs on the devtools console?  Is your AJAX request really working correctly, and returning the JSON as expected (check devtools network tab).  Minor suggestion - it is much harder to read and spot problems in JS when it is all compressed and formatted like that.  Easy readability means easier to understand and spot problems.

Comment: @Don't Panic no errors in Explorer or Chrome developer tab. And found by checking it in Explorer and Edge this morning that it works and displays correctly in both, so this is a Chrome only issue. AJAX and JSON are both doing as expected. The array is passed from php, it is utf8_encode and then returned via json_encode using JSON_FORCE_OBJECT.    I do not know how to supply the JS array, I will try to do a JSFiddle and will edit my original question to explain the code better - thanks

Comment: Where did you evaluate the displayed output? Did you check the dome in dev tools?

Comment: @ClausBönnhoff If I write it to the container as text and not html I get perfectly formed html as desired (as shown in my question). This is not displaying the html in Chrome, in IE and Edge it works. I do not get any devtools errors in IE or Chrome. I'm not sure what I'm missing here - I don't know how to do the JSFiddle because I can't get the array into it. thanks.

Comment: That does not answer my question. Did you ever take alook at the dome in the dev tools using the inspect button on the top left of the dev tools window or with the elemnts tab

Comment: @ClausBönnhoff I was not familiar with that - sorry for missing it in your question. I am still not sure what its telling me. When I click on the element using the button at the top left it displays the correct content! on the right on the code line it has "==$0" after it and at the bottom is says: [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.  does that help?

Comment: The deprecated means, that you are using synchrones requesst with ajax which is a very bad solution but it should have nothing to do with the error itself. But you should switch to asynchronous request asap. The "==$0" looks more like the reason for the error. Can you make a screenshot of the element?

Comment: @ClausBönnhoff screen shot of console added to question - is this what you are looking for?

Comment: At the moment I am out of ideas. You can only try to remove your classes. Eventually they have some unknown declaration for chrome?

Comment: @ClausBönnhoff Thanks - I will keep playing with it and post what I find.

Comment: The errors in red at the bottom right of your screenshot (the console) - what does that say? At top right of devtools there is 1 yellow triangle - that means a warning on the console, my guess is that will be the deprecated msg.  There is also 1 red cross - that's an error, my guess is that is the red text partially displayed in the console, and could be the current problem?

Comment: @Don'tPanic   the yellow triangle error is:  [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience.  (the red at the bottom in the screen shot I cannot get to repeat, not sure what I did in the screen shot to get them)

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be if the container div has a min-height and the content dynamically loaded into that container does not fill it Chrome chooses not to show the content loaded, the error in the console is:

[Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience.

Simple fix is to not set the min-height on the div that will receive the new dynamic content. It has to be inside another div that does have the min-height.